# Java put method what is the purpose to call compare with itself

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I was reading java source code of TreeMap, for the put method, when the map is empty, it still calling compare key with itself, what is the purpose of that?
'''

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
        TreeMap.Entry<K, V> t = this.root;
        if (t == null) {
            this.compare(key, key);
            this.root = new TreeMap.Entry(key, value, (TreeMap.Entry)null);
            this.size = 1;
            ++this.modCount;
            return null;
        }
```

'''

Answer (score 6):

Checks.

Specifically, the `compare` method will toss both the first and second argument (in this case, it's the same thing) at the comparator if it is defined. In which case, if there's a problem with the comparator (for example, the comparator you fed to the TreeMap is designed to compare strings, but it's a map of integers - remember, TreeMap **predates** generics, there is no guarantee that `key` is of the correct type) - then this will throw an exception now.

That's a good thing - you want exceptions to occur as early as possible.

Even if there is no comparator defined (i.e. you're going by natural sorting order), this will then cast the `key` to `Comparable`, which will throw a ClassCastException if it does not implement the method.

Finally, if you're attempting to add `null` to the treemap and the comparator doesn't like it (or it's a comparator-less TreeMap), then you get an NPE.

TL;DR: The `compare()` call either does nothing, or throws an exception, which is the point: Throw early.